# Database table to ajax call in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So i have a table with a bunch of data inside (inside the table is a bunch of columns).

Now i'm wanting to have this table only return the data that matches data from another table.

Basically one table will have a link inside it. lets call it `link A` in `Table A`

In `Table B` there is also a link which matches exactly to `link A` Lets call that `link B`

Now. I have an ajax call in javascript. It looks like this.

```
var contentType ="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

  if(window.XDomainRequest) contentType = "text/plain";


      $.ajax({

        debugger;

        beforeSend: function (xhr){
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
        },
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: '',
        success: function(json) {
          //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < json.TicketGroups.length; i++) {
            var section = json.TicketGroups[i].TicketTypeName;
            var tid = json.TicketGroups[i].Id.slice(1);
            var no = json.TicketGroups[i].QtyOptions;
            var row = json.TicketGroups[i].Row;
            var price = json.TicketGroups[i].Price;
            var notes = json.TicketGroups[i].notes;
            var button =
            "<a class='btn btn-info' data-url=''>Buy Now</a>";
            $("#tableid").append("<tr><td><img id='theImg' src='/assets/seatwave-logo.png'/></td><td><b>" + section +
            "</b></td><td><b>" + no + "</b></td><td><b>£" + price + "</b></td><td><b>N/A</b></td><td><b>£" + price +"</b></td><td><b>" + button + "</b></td></tr>");
            $("#tableid").find(".btn.btn-info").click(function() {
              location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
            });
          }
          sortTable();
        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
```

This js handles the appending the data to the table. (however im not sure how to get the information from the database into here yet)

So `link A` will look for `link b` inside `table b` Then it will pass all the results matched into the javascript file. `Link A` is defined in the view under the id params.

How do i go abut making this work? i can attempt to explain better if you'd like I havent even got the data being pulled from the database so i can see it with byebug yet! haha

Comment: Are you calling ajax on your own rails application to get data from database?

Comment: Thats what im wanting to do, the data is in my database so it is a local ajax call ill be trying to make unless you can think of a better way to do it (baring in mind that other ajax calls are into the same table connecting to an api)

Comment: If you want to serve content just based on values in your database, you should use preprocessing engine like erb(default in rails) or haml which lets you write ruby code inside the html. This ruby code gets executed before the content is served.
If not read the answer I have posted.